# Permission Denied error while starting httpd service

Tags: apache-http-server

I am getting "Permission denied" error while starting the "httpd" service using "sudo service httpd start" command on a RHEL 6.10 server.
Below is the exact error:

> Syntax error on line 221 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error
>   on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/verint.conf: Cannot load
>   /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so into server:
>   /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   Permission denied

I request someone to please help me to resolve this error